# Notification when GridViewColumn has its ActualWidth changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a table with three columns where the middle column automatically fills the available horizontal space.

So I listen to the `Loaded` and `SizeChanged` event (for when the table is resized) and assign widths based on a simple calculation:

```
private void table_Resize(ListView listView)
{
    var _ActualWidth = listView.ActualWidth - gridSplitter.Width - 5;
    GridView _GridView = listView.View as GridView;

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < _GridView.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1) continue;
        _ActualWidth -= _GridView.Columns[i].ActualWidth;
    }
    if (_ActualWidth > 0)
    {
        _GridView.Columns[1].Width = _ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when data is added to the underlying `ListView` then this can force a column to change its width.

I figure that I need my program to get notified when the `ActualWidth` of a `GridViewColumn` is changed (increased) so that I can recompute the column widths accordingly.

Comment: I think I can subclass the grid view column and add code to ``ActualWidth.set`` which triggers a notification, but I'm not sure how or if this is the right approach.

Comment: Please post some actual code so we can help you!

Comment: Consider using the [ListView Layout Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25058/ListView-Layout-Manager)

Comment: How about listen to Data Context Changed? The column i think inherits from FrameworkElement so it doesn't have the loaded, size changed event, etc... You can make a behavior to achieve something along the lines... but that's about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subclassing solution won't work. First, `ActualWidth` is not virtual afaik, secondly, `ActualWidth` has `private` setter. If you check [GridViewColumn](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/GridViewColumn.cs,4d3e88d5f2b1ed42) source code, you'll see it's already raising notification.

You could do it this way:

```
myColumns[i].PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
  if(e.PropertyName == "ActualWidth"){
    // do something here..
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be ``(INotifyPropertyChanged)myColumns[i]).PropertyChanged``.